# How to use gradle without maven

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to use gradle without maven?
I ask this question because I've encounered a case where it isn't possible. For example, I have a project(let it be `project A`) which results in a jar file after the build. This project is used by another project(`project B`). When I change smth in project A, project B has to see those changes. In maven we could simply make `mvn install` on project A, then refresh dependencies on project B and changes hapen to be seen there(in project B)

Gradle has an opportunity to use maven plugin which can do the descibed thing. But in that case we rely on maven(maven repo in particular). I was founding information(seems on stackoverflow also) that gradle filestore, which is located in `GRADLE_USER_HOME`, is only a cache and can't be used for such purpose.

So, how to achieve that functionality in gradle

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle downloads dependencies from repositories. These repositories can be Maven repositories, Ivy repositories, local Maven repositories or file repositories. So, to solve your use-case, you would indeed have to publish A to a repository, and to use this repository as the source of the A dependency in B.

See [the documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec%3arepositories) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I understood. Gradle doesn't need maven. If we are going to refer to maven local repo, gradle will create that repo under USER_HOME/.m2(previously creating .m2 foder of course) and `apply plugin: 'maven'` simply allow us to use `gradle install` command